# Date range filter does not work

Tags: php

Filter with fields "PREGLEDALI","PREGLEDA1","PREGLEDA2" works perfectly, but the date range filter not work. I have the date format (01.10.2013) in database.

```
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM preglediv1 WHERE NOW() BETWEEN '%s".$start."%s' AND  '%s".$end."%s'");
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM preglediv1 WHERE (`pregledali` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`pregleda1` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`pregleda2` LIKE '%".$query."%')")
    or die(mysql_error());
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
        while($results = mysql_fetch_array($result))
```

Comment: A good way to debug this sort of thing is to assign your query to a string variable in each case (I use `$sql`). This makes it easy to `echo` out what the query contains. The first thing I then do is to run it in the database, and work out from there why it gives unexpected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you've provided I can see two issues:

- you are overwriting the data in `$result` in the second call to mysql_query()
- you are also looking for the current date (`NOW()`) to be between your constraints.

Assuming that you're using a DATE or DATETIME column in MySQL rather than a VARCHAR you can do the following ($start and $end should be formatted as ["yyyy-MM-dd"](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM preglediv1 WHERE [nameofdatecolumn] BETWEEN '" . $start . "' AND '" . $end . "' AND " .
            "(`pregledali` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`pregleda1` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`pregleda2` LIKE '%".$query."%')";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: Ty very much Rob, i post whole code you will see where i make mistake.